# Cannot ping hosts in mininet

Tags: mininet

I have the following code in python for mininet and I am trying to pingall but no package is received. I have no idea what is wrong. When I write `h1 ping -c 1 h2` it gives me the error:

> ping: r1: Name or service not known

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.nodelib import LinuxBridge
from mininet.log import setLogLevel

if __name__ == '__main__':
setLogLevel('info')

net = Mininet(switch=LinuxBridge, controller=None)

# create rest of the topology here
h1 = net.addHost('h1', ip=None)
h2 = net.addHost('h2', ip=None)
r1 = net.addHost('r1', ip=None)
r2 = net.addHost('r2', ip=None)

s0 = net.addSwitch('s0')
s1 = net.addSwitch('s1')
s2 = net.addSwitch('s2')

r1.cmd('sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1')
r2.cmd('sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1')

net.addLink(h1, s1)
net.addLink(r1, s1)
net.addLink(r1, s0)
net.addLink(r2, s0)
net.addLink(r2, s2)
net.addLink(h2, s2)

h1.cmd("ip -6 addr add 2001:638:709:a::1/64 dev h1-eth0")
h2.cmd("ip -6 addr add 2001:638:709:b::1/64 dev h2-eth0")
r1.cmd("ip -6 addr add 2001:638:709:a::f/64 dev r1-eth0")
r1.cmd("ip -6 addr add 2001:638:709:f::1/64 dev r1-eth1")
r2.cmd("ip -6 addr add 2001:638:709:f::2/64 dev r2-eth0")
r2.cmd("ip -6 addr add 2001:638:709:b::f/64 dev r2-eth1")

h1.cmd("ip -6 route add 2001:638:709::/48 via 2001:638:709:a::f dev h1-eth0")
r1.cmd("ip -6 route add 2001:638:709:b::/64 via 2001:638:709:f::2 dev r1-eth1")

r2.cmd("ip -6 route add 2001:638:709:a::/64 via 2001:638:709:f::1 dev r2-eth0")

h2.cmd("ip -6 route add 2001:638:709::/48 via 2001:638:709:b::f dev h2-eth0")

net.start()
CLI(net)
net.stop()
```

Comment: Do you find solution? If not have you tried some IP address at `r1 = net.addHost('r1', ip=None)` like `r1 = net.addHost('r1', ip=127.0.0.1)`?

Answer (score 0):

"Name or service not known" would indicate that there was a lookup failure and the name r1 can't be resolved to an IP address. You could verify that with an nslookup (or dig) command.